# Shifting each row differently of a given range with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table with 3 columns and 30 rows. I am trying to write a VBA macro that shifts first row with 1 cell to the right, the second row 2 cells to the right and so on.

For example, this

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

should look like this:

```
 AAA
  BBB
   CCC
```

What I tried so far, could only move the whole selected range:

```
Sub Macro()
Set Table = Application.InputBox("Select table", Title:="Table", Type:=8)
Table.Cut Table.Offset(0, 1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be doing what you want:

```
Sub Macro()

Set Table = Application.InputBox("Select table", Title:="Table", Type:=8)
Set Dest = Application.InputBox("Select destination", Title:="Destination", Type:=8)

For i = 1 To Table.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To Table.Columns.Count
         Table.Cells(i, j).Copy Dest.Cells(i + j - 1, i + 1)
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Before:

[image]

The code:

```
Sub asdfg()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        Cells(i, 1).Cut (Cells(i, i + 1))
    Next i
End Sub
```

and after:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To shift the **entire row** use:

```
Sub zxcvb()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, i)).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Next i
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

Comment: @Lanza  Do you want the entire row shifted ??

Comment: I want to shift the first row of the selection with 1 cell to the right, the second row 2cells to the right and so on.

Comment: @Lanza  See my **EDIT#1**